# Computing a convolution using FFT and more than minimum number of samples

Tags: matlab, fft, convolution

Assume vector s is a set of time samples of length 1000.
Assume vector h is a set of samples of length 50.

If I want to compute the convolution of those vectors, the result will be 1000+50-1 = 1049 points long, as expected.

If I want instead to calculate this using an FFT, I need to ensure that the circular convolution does not alias.  Therefore, the FFT size of each vector must be >= 1049.  However,  I want an efficient FFT length, so I compute a 2048 size FFT of each vector, multiply them together, and take the ifft.  This leaves me with a 2048 point answer.

In MATLAB:

```
H = fftshift(fft(h,2048));
S = fftshift(fft(s,2048));
result = fftshift(ifft(H.*S));
```

That result contains "extra" samples because of the fft zero padding.  Theoretically it contains exactly 999 extra samples that I need to throw out.  What's the systematic way to know exactly which samples of the resulting vector to throw away?

Comment: All the extra samples are zeros at the end. Makes them easy to find :-)

Comment: For this example, the direct linear convolution is significantly more efficient than doing 3 2048 point FFTs.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Simply keep the first 1049 samples of the IFFT result and throw the rest away.

You don't have to do a `fftshift`

```
y1 = conv(s,h);
y2 = ifft(fft(s, 2048) .* fft(h, 2048));
figure; plot(y1); hold on; plot(y2(1:length(y1)), '--');
```

BTW, compared to linear convolution, it is more efficient to use FFT when `s` and `h` have similar lengths. In your case uniformly breaking the long signal `s` into several small blocks and then applying [overlap-add](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Overlap%E2%80%93add_method) or [overlap-save](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Overlap%E2%80%93save_method) should be a better solution.

Comment: Thanks.  It appears that all of the 'fftshift's I was doing were causing me my problems.